# Looking for a standard undergraduate introduction to congruence.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, self-learning

I'm self-studying number theory and am looking for a standard undergraduate introduction to congruence.

Hardy and Wright has it in pieces that can be uncovered.
Gauss, of course, in *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* has *the* presentation in the history of mathematics.
Ogilvy's *Excursions in Number Theory* has a nice intuitive presentation.
I like the newer text by Watkins ...

But what I seek is a step-by-step introduction to the theory of congruences that is not leading anywhere in particular *except* that it would be a solid foundation to move on.

Anybody have a good set of lecture notes out there?

My plan starts with equivalence relations, partitions, etc. and then moves on to congruence.

This may be asking for too many personal opinions but, in a phrase:

what, in your opinion, is a good source for an introduction to congruence?

Comment: A great place to ask for references is /r/math (the math subreddit). Personally, I would recommend an introductory book in proofs. Most such books cover congruences, relations and partitions. I would also recommend Alan Baker's Concise book but, as the title says, it is fairly concise.

Comment: Maybe you like the book 'Introduction to Analytic Number Theory' written by Tom Apostol. However, the requirements for this book is some knowledge of basic analysis.